# Is there a way to determinate the type of request received in a Class Based View with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have a Django Rest Framework API service **that I want to re-use in my frontend app**, but I have some doubts related of the best way to determinate the kind of request that the endpoint receive.

I have a structure like below:

```
core
api
web
```

And I call my endpoints from my web app to my api app. At the moment, I'm not using any frontend framework, just only django, so i send data from my web app to api in this way: **_customdictionary.custom_dictionary_kpi({"language": 1, "user": 1})**, look that I'm not doing a POST request in this case, I just only send a dictionary with 2 values: **language** and **user**, that I defined in my serializers:

serializers.py

```
class CustomDictionaryKpiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomDictionary
        fields = ('user','language')
```

web/views.py

```
class CustomDictionaryView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            _customdictionary = CustomDictionaryViewSet()
            _customdictionary.custom_dictionary_kpi({"language": 1, "user": 1}) # Here i send my data
            '''some logic'''            
        except Exception as e:
            '''handle exception'''
        return render(request,template_name='web/dictionary_get.html',status=self.code,context=self.response_data)
```

Then I receive the data in api/api.py with **request['field_name']**

```
class CustomDictionaryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomDictionary.objects.filter(
        is_active=True,
        is_deleted=False
    ).order_by('id')
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.response_data = {'error': [], 'data': {}}
        self.code = 0

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'custom_dictionary_kpi':
            return CustomDictionaryKpiSerializer
        return CustomDictionarySerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def custom_dictionary_kpi(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            queryset = CustomDictionary.objects.filter(
                is_active=True,
                is_deleted=False,
                language_id=request['language'],
                user_id=request['user']
            ).order_by('id')
                '''some logic'''
        except Exception as e:
            '''handle error'''
        return Response(self.response_data,status=self.code)
```

The problem is that if I send a POST request in the DRF API (HTML Form), catching the request like: **request['field_name']**

Doesn't work by reason:

```
*** TypeError: 'Request' object is not subscriptable
```

It works with:

```
request.POST.get('<field_name>')
```

Or

```
request.data['<field_name>']
```

Receiving the user or language in Str type. A similar problem happens if i send data in DFR API, but in Raw data, It doesn't work with:
`request['field_name']`

By reason:

```
*** TypeError: 'Request' object is not subscriptable
```

Neither with:

```
request.POST.get('<field_name>')
```

Because it's None, it works with:

```
request.data['<field_name>']
```

Receiving the user or language in Integer type. I know that if I use a frontend framework, I could send a request to my endpoint and then get the data in the same way than DRF API:

```
request.POST.get('<field_name>')
```

Or

```
request.data['<field_name>']
```

I suppose that i need a method that validate the type of request, something like:

```
def validate(self,request):
   try:
      if request['field_name']:
         '''some logic'''
   except Exception as e:
      if request.POST.get('field_name'):
         '''some logic'''
```

So, is there an elegant way to validate the type of request?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

If this `validation` method is common for some endpoints one of the best practices is to use decorator to validate some information from request object. Say in decorators.py we have `validate_field_name` decorator that is useful `custom_dictionary_kpi` api end-point validations. So

In decorators.py

```py
from functools import wraps
from rest_framework import exceptions


def validate_field_name(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        errors = {}
        try:
            if request['field_name']:
                '''some logic'''
        except Exception as e:
            if request.POST.get('field_name'):
                '''some logic'''
        if errors:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(errors)
        return f(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator
```

And In our views.py

```py
from .decorators import validate_field_name

class CustomDictionaryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    "" All your necessary codes "" 
    @validate_field_name
    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def custom_dictionary_kpi(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            queryset = CustomDictionary.objects.filter(
                is_active=True,
                is_deleted=False,
                language_id=request['language'],
                user_id=request['user']
            ).order_by('id')
                '''some logic'''
        except Exception as e:
            '''handle error'''
        return Response(self.response_data,status=self.code)
```

#### References

1. what is decorators in python, [link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decorators-python)
2. [functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mxing django's and DRF's request object. Because on every request Django set a request object containing multiple headers. But DRF extends this `HttpRequest` object  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/ as DRF's `Request` object given in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/ . So to understand which type of request you are getting you need see the attributes present. For example Django's POST data is present in `request.POST` request object but for DRF it i present in `request.data`. Similarly in django GET data is present in `request.DATA` but for DRF its in `request.query_params` . For more attributes refers to the docs  link given above.

Answer (score 0):

According with @Shakil answer and type of request like @Abhimanyu Singh said, this was my solution, I hope to be useful for anyone else:

In a instance of a CBV (in web/views.py), sending params like:

```
_instance= MyNameViewSet()
_instance.endpoint_name(request,param1=1,param2=1)
```

Request validation is like that:

```
from functools import wraps
from rest_framework import exceptions

def validate_field_name(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if(len(kwargs) > 0):
            # HTML template
            kwargs['data'] = kwargs
        # DRF API View, Postman POST request made by body (JSON)
        elif len(args[1].data) > 0:
            kwargs['data'] = args[1].data
        # Postman POST request made by params
        elif len(args[1].query_params.dict()) > 0:
            kwargs['data'] = args[1].query_params.dict()
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return decorator
```

This return a dict, then in your api.py, you can access like:

```
kwargs['data']['param1']
```